# How to add colored Image to project android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-drawable

I try to add an image as drawable to my kotlin project, so i can use it in an imagebutton, but my problem is i can't add it. I tried to import it with the Image Assets, but that only generates a gray picture, but i want it colored. So how can i add a colored picture to my project with android studio?

Comment: Copy it into your desired resource directory.

Comment: How is it being decolored, can you check if the image has color first. Because Android doesnot remove or add filter on images by default.

Answer (score 0):

From the tool, select resource Manager and click the plus icon, then select Import Drawable.

tool> resource Manager>+>Import Drawable